# Prove the Alternating Series Test using Cauchy Criterion.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

The Alternating Series Test : Suppose $(a_n)$ is a sequence

1. $a_1 >= a_2 >= a_3 >=...$

2. $lim$ $a_n$=0

Then $\sum_{i=1}^n $$(-1)^n$.$a_n$ converges where n--> inf.

My Attempt:

Given lim $a_n$=0. So for $\epsilon$ > 0 and n >= N, we have |$a_n$| < $\epsilon$.

Consider |$s_n - s_m$| = |$a_{m+1}$ - $a_{m+2}$ + $a_{m+3}$ - $a_{m+4}$ +……$+-$ $a_n$|
<= |$a_{m+1}$| + |- $a_{m+2}$| + |$a_{m+3}$| + ….. + |+-$a_n$|
<  (n - m).$\epsilon$, whenever m, n >= N.

Put $\epsilon_0$ = (m + n).$\epsilon$ and we get |$s_n - s_m$| < $\epsilon_0$

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You cannot make $\epsilon_0$ dependent on $n$ and $m$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Hint can be to consider $S_{2n}$ partial sums and use monotonic.

Comment: https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/AlternatingSeries.aspx

Comment: I'm writing my second attempt in the answers. Please give it a check :)

Answer (score 1):

For m,n > l, |$s_n - s_m$| = |$a_{m+1} - a_{m+2} + a_{m+3} - … +-a_n$| <= $a_l$ .....(1)

Since $lim a_n$ = 0, there exists N s.t |$a_l$| < $\epsilon$ whenever l >= N.....(2)

From (1) and (2),

|$s_n - s_m$| < $\epsilon$

Comment: Can you explain why statement (1) is true?